# Celery/ RabbitMQ Permissions Management - Configuration of Exchanges/Queues

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

I have a celery Application with queue Declaration as such.

```
app.conf.CELERY_QUEUES = (
    Queue('default', routing_key='default'),
    Queue('classifier', routing_key='classifier'),
    Queue('clients', routing_key='clients'),
    Queue('bookings', routing_key='bookings'),
    Queue('ingestor', routing_key='ingestor'),
    Queue('typeahead', routing_key='typeahead')
)
```

My DevOps team has recent set up a RabbitMQ User with permissions as such. [image]

They have mentioned that    they do not intend to give any configuration privileges to the user since if a hacker gets those credentials they can delete queues etc.,

When I start up the celery worker it fails to authorize

> amqp.exceptions.AccessRefused: Exchange.declare: (403) ACCESS_REFUSED
>   - access t o exchange 'celeryev' in vhost '/' refused for user 'test'

While testing, I gave myself explicit configure to celery*.

This was able to get past that issue, but then it started complaining about the same issue for my default/classifier queues, which already exist, and should not need to be configured, so I have a few questions.

1) Does celery need configure privileges in order for it to work?

2) If not, why is it trying to configure a queue that already exists? As seen in this  image.
[image]

3) Is there an actual security concern with just turning on this to permission with '.*'

4) is there a way to tell celery to just read and write? and not to worry about configuring anything?

PLease let me know if there are any thoughts . I have been using this issue for guidance, but have not figured it out yet.

https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/3895

I am using Celery 3.1.24

Comment: Is the solution provided in [this comment](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/3895#issuecomment-294320123) not valid?

Comment: It only works on Celery v4, but I am version locked on celery 3 as of now @LukeBakken

Comment: You will have to upgrade Celery or grant the appropriate permission. It is a common pattern with RabbitMQ to always declare a queue before using it. If the queue already exists, there is no harm in doing so.